# How to hide and password protect an image stored on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

how to hide any image stored in iPhone. And also how to password protect that image using XCODE.

Comment: From user point of view or from code?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?

As I understand it, if you store an image in your application, only your application can access it. Your application would be the only possible way to access the images, so I wouldn't think that you'd have to do anything complicated to hide it or restrict access. Just ask for a password in your app before you display the image.

If you want to protect an image in the standard Photos application then I'm sure that that's not possible. The user would always be able to view it in the Photos application.

Images in other applications are also not accessible from your application, so there's nothing you can do there.